# Add floating view (i.e. static and fixed) to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to add a custom subview to a `UITableViewController` that doesn't move when the user scrolls.

Is it possible to add such a view?

I'm using a `UITableViewController`. I would switch to a `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView`, but the code relies on the UITableViewController's `refreshControl`. Adding a container view and having two controllers seems a bit much for such a simple task!

I've also tried adding the content to the `UINavigationController` view, but unfortunately it doesn't animate smoothly when the view controller appears and disappears.

Is there any way to add a fixed subview to a `UITableView`?

**Edit:**

Adding a container view and having two controllers (with an embed segue) is difficult for this project, since I'm updating an older code base and there is a lot of legacy code that depends on the main controller being a `UITableViewController`. Is there any way to achieve this without an embed segue / two view controllers?

Comment: See also the similar [Disable tableHeaderView -- not to be confused with section header -- scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18563172)

Comment: Just added the [answer I was typing here to the duped question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26370964/1445366).

Comment: This is great! Thanks for nominating the duplicate questions. My only concern is that a lot of these answers say "add a container view"; it might be good to have a canonical solution which doesn't require a container view and embed segue. Aaron has a good answer and this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18565273/746890) is pretty good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put buttons over UITableView which won't scroll with table in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689805/how-to-put-buttons-over-uitableview-which-wont-scroll-with-table-in-ios)

Comment: There are a few questions on SO that deal with similar issues, but I haven't found any prior questions that specifically exclude switching to a `UIViewController`. I think it's good to have a canonical solution for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately creating a container view for a `UITableViewController` inside of a `UIViewController` isn't feasible in this case. [That is a great solution if you're early enough in development to arrange things properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17825708/746890).

The best solution I've found, is to transform the floating view's `y` position on `scrollViewDidScroll` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18565273/746890):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.header.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

I have seen other answers which modify the floating view's frame, but I think transforming is probably more appropriate.

As an interesting aside, I was able to create a floating view that 'dismisses' when the user scrolls down, but 'floats' when the user pulls to refresh by checking the table view offset before applying the transform.

Comment: Thanks! In case you have insets, you'll need to take account of that: `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y + self.tableView.contentInset.top);`

Comment: put that in "viewDidLayoutSubviews", which is called for every frame when scrolling, e.g. `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        noDataLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: tableView.contentOffset.y)
    }`