# Is it possible to use storyboards to create a static table using UIViewController instead of UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uitableview

I am hoping that it is possible to create static table with out using UITableViewController, but I haven't found the answer yet.

The reason I need to use a normal UIViewController is that I have items above where I need the table to start. Such as custom buttons, status indicator, images, and a toolbar. Here is an image so you can see what I am talking about.

[image]

I have multiple form fields and other things in each custom cell. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed a `UITableViewController` into your `UIViewController` as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825226/toolbar-between-uinavigationbar-and-uitableview/17825708#17825708) using embed segue.

Comment: I see your method there, but in this case wouldn't it be the same to just use instantiateViewController?

Comment: More or less. But the embed segue sets up the view and view controller containment relationships for you and you can visually see how things are wired together in the storyboard.

Comment: @Cedric If you manually instantiate the view controller, then you have to do the `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController` calls, too. The embed segue (iOS6 and later, only) does all of that for you.